# Take latest result where result more than one

Tags: sql-server

My table stores clock out times, but some of the them will punch more than 1 time. How to get the latest result where result more than one?

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.USERID, day(l.CHECKTIME), DATEPART(hh, l.CHECKTIME) ORDER BY (select 0)) RN, 
    l.USERID,
    CASE 
       WHEN CAST(l.CHECKTIME AS TIME) > = CAST(SC.EndTime AS TIME) 
          THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(l.CHECKTIME AS TIME), 100)
          ELSE 'Early ClockOut ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CAST(l.CHECKTIME AS TIME), 100) 
    END as ClockOut,l.CHECKTIME
FROM
    CHECKINOUT l
INNER JOIN  
    USERINFO u ON l.USERID = u.USERID
INNER JOIN 
    UserUsedSClasses uuc ON uuc.USERID = u.USERID
INNER JOIN 
    SchClass SC ON uuc.SchId = SC.schClassid
WHERE 
    u.BADGENUMBER not in (79,103,78) 
    AND MONTH(CHECKTIME) = MONTH(getdate()) AND YEAR(CHECKTIME) = YEAR(getdate())
    AND uuc.SchId = 1
    AND DATEPART (hh, l.CHECKTIME) >= DATEPART(hh, SC.EndTime)
    AND DATEPART(hh, l.CHECKTIME) >= DATEPART (hh, SC.StartTime) 
ORDER BY 
    u.BADGENUMBER
```

Output:

```
RN  USERID  ClockOut    CHECKTIME
1   6       7:04PM      2017-03-09 19:04:12.000 
2   6       7:55PM      2017-03-09 19:55:59.000  
1   6       11:31PM     2017-03-09 23:31:27.000
```

should be show this result only:

```
RN  USERID  ClockOut    CHECKTIME
-----------------------------------------------
1   6       11:31PM     2017-03-09 23:31:27.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `row_number()`, change your `order by` to `l.CHECKTIME desc` and then filter on `where rn = 1` using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) or subquery.

To get the latest checkout per day, change your `partition by` to `l.userid, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, l.checktime), 0)` to truncate the datetime to just the date (you could also use `convert(date,l.checktime)`).

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
;with cte as (
  select 
      rn = row_number() over (
        partition by l.userid, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, l.checktime), 0)
        order by l.checktime desc
      )
    , l.userid
    , Clockout = case 
        when cast(l.checktime as time) >= cast(sc.EndTime as time)
          then convert(varchar(100), cast(l.checktime as time), 100)
        else 'Early ClockOut ' + convert(varchar(100), cast(l.checktime as time), 100)
        end
    , l.checktime
    , u.badgenumber
  from checkinout l
    inner join userinfo u
      on l.userid = u.userid
    inner join UserUsedsclasses uuc
      on uuc.userid = u.userid
    inner join SchClass sc
      on uuc.SchId = sc.schClassid
  where uuc.SchId = 1
    and u.badgenumber not in (79, 103, 78)
    and l.checktime >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() )  , 0)
    and l.checktime <  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() )+1, 0)
    and datepart(hour, l.checktime) >= datepart(hour, sc.EndTime)
    and datepart(hour, l.checktime) >= datepart(hour, sc.StartTime)
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
order by badgenumber;
```

or without the cte

```
select *
from (
  select 
      rn = row_number() over (
        partition by l.userid, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, l.checktime), 0)
        order by l.checktime desc
      )
    , l.userid
    , Clockout = case 
        when cast(l.checktime as time) >= cast(sc.EndTime as time)
          then convert(varchar(100), cast(l.checktime as time), 100)
        else 'Early ClockOut ' + convert(varchar(100), cast(l.checktime as time), 100)
        end
    , l.checktime
    , u.badgenumber
  from checkinout l
    inner join userinfo u
      on l.userid = u.userid
    inner join UserUsedsclasses uuc
      on uuc.userid = u.userid
    inner join SchClass sc
      on uuc.SchId = sc.schClassid
  where uuc.SchId = 1
    and u.badgenumber not in (79, 103, 78)
    and l.checktime >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() )  , 0)
    and l.checktime <  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() )+1, 0)
    and datepart(hour, l.checktime) >= datepart(hour, sc.EndTime)
    and datepart(hour, l.checktime) >= datepart(hour, sc.StartTime)
  ) as sub
where rn = 1
order by badgenumber;
```

---

And a faster way to perform:

```
AND MONTH(CHECKTIME) = MONTH(getdate()) 
AND YEAR(CHECKTIME)  = YEAR(getdate())
```

is

```
and l.checktime >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() )  , 0) /* month start*/
and l.checktime <  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() )+1, 0) /* next month start */
```